# SonarQube gives ValueTask instances returned from method calls should be directly awaited issue

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, sonarqube, valuetask

In my .NET project test project I have method like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task SampleMethod()
{
  // given
  Guid someRoleId = Guid.NewGuid();
  NpgsqlException npgsqlException = GetNpsqlException();

  var failedRoleStorageException = new FailedRoleStorageException(npgsqlException);

  var expectedRoleDependencyException = new RoleDependencyException(failedRoleStorageException);

  this.dataMock.SelectRoleByIdAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>()).Throws(npgsqlException);

  // when
  ValueTask<Role> roleByIdTask = this.roleService.RoleByIdAsync(someRoleId);

  // then
  RoleDependencyException actualServiceException = await Assert.ThrowsAsync < DependencyException > (() => roleByIdTask.AsTask());

  actualServiceException.Should().BeEquivalentTo(
  expectedRoleDependencyException);

  await this.dataMock.Received(1).SelectRoleByIdAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>());

  this.dataMock.ClearReceivedCalls();
}
```

In the above code this line gives me following SonarQube code smell.

> `ValueTask` instances returned from method calls should be directly awaited, returned, or passed as an argument to another method call. Other usage, such as storing an instance into a local or a field, is likely an indication of a bug, as `ValueTask` instances must only ever be consumed once.

So I try to resolve it like this,

```
[Fact]
public async Task SampleMethod()
{
    // given
    Guid someRoleId = Guid.NewGuid();
    NpgsqlException npgsqlException = GetNpsqlException();

    var failedRoleStorageException = new FailedRoleStorageException(npgsqlException);
    var expectedRoleDependencyException = new RoleDependencyException(failedRoleStorageException);

    this.dataMock.SelectRoleByIdAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>()).Throws(npgsqlException);

    // when and then
    RoleDependencyException actualServiceException = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<RoleDependencyException>(
        () => this.roleService.RoleByIdAsync(someRoleId).AsTask());

    actualServiceException.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedRoleDependencyException);

    await this.dataMock.Received(1).SelectRoleByIdAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>());

    this.dataMock.ClearReceivedCalls();
}
```

In there I directly await the `ValueTask` without storing it in a variable. But it's also not the solution for me. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: *"But it's also not the solution for me."* -- Why? What's the problem with this solution?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias provided answer helped me to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `.AsTask()` at the end of your method.

```
this.dataBrokerMock.SelectRoleByIdAsync(Arg.Any<Guid>()).AsTask().Throws(npgsqlException);
```

https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-5034/